# Export table to drive "User memory limit exceeded" on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, random-forest

I'm exporting the table from the random forest model result, showing the relationship between the predicted values and the observed values in terms of the training data. However, when I ran the task and attempt to download into my Google Drive, the error says **"Error: User memory limit exceeded. (Error code: 3)".**

These are the codes:

```
var random = s1s2_sample.randomColumn()
var validation = random.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',0.2)) //<
var training = random.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',0.2))  //>=

var variables2021 = ['VV','VH','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12','NDVI','RVI','EVI','NDVIn','NDVIre','DVI','Vigreen','GNDVI','SAVI','MSAVI','ARVI','NDI45'];

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'AGB_DW',
  inputProperties: variables2021
}).setOutputMode('REGRESSION');

var classified2021 = S1S2_2021m.select(variables2021).classify(classifier).toInt();

// Get predicted regression points in same location as training data
var predictedTraining = classified2021.sampleRegions({collection:trainingData, geometries: true, scale: 10, projection: 'EPSG:3006'});
//print(predictedTraining);

// Separate the observed (AGB) and predicted (regression) properties
var sampleTraining = predictedTraining.select(['AGB_DW', 'classification']);
//print(sampleTraining);

//Export R square.table.toDrive(
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: sampleTraining,
  description: '2021Sample_Predict_Observe_Training',
  folder: '2021AGB',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```

I have used the same code to process the data for other years, and they worked properly, so I think the code itself may be fine. Perhaps the data for this year is too large to process, though I also set the tileScale to 16. Are there any ways that I can export the data successfully?

I was also thinking to separate the data into two parts and process them separately. However, it would be a problem if I try to see the relative importance of each variable in terms of the whole study area. Therefore, I hope there will be some ways I can download this table at once.